# Difference between func() and (*this).func() in C++

Tags: c++, dispatch

I am working on someone else code in C++, and I found a weird call to a certain function `func()`. Here is an example:

```
if(condition)
    func();
else
    (*this).func();
```

What is the difference between `func()` and `(*this).func()`?

What are the cases where the call to `func()` and `(*this).func()` will execute different code?

In my case, `func()` is not a macro. It is a virtual function in the base class, with an implementation in both base and derived class, and no free `func()`. The `if` is located in a method in the base class.

Comment: Does the class have default values that are overwritten later?

Comment: Is it in a class template?

Comment: Is this code located in the base class or in the derived class?

Comment: Not that it matters much, but `(*this).func()` is more readable as `this->func()`

Comment: @ringø This is highly debatable...

Comment: Operator overloading on '*'?

Comment: @pjc50 you cannot overload `*` for primitive types and `this` is a keyword which alvays evaluates to rvalue of pointer type.

Comment: @LukeG Debatable, certainly. But most of the code I see uses `->`, operator that has been created for a reason. Similarly, `a[X]` is usually preferred to `*(a+X)`. This makes me think that *"someone else code"* may not be doing what the author intended it to do ; maybe he thought the first one would call the base class implementation...

Comment: Do you want to provide the full context of the code so that people don't have to guess?

Comment: Have you tried compiling to assembly and see what the compiler generates ? With g++, use -S

Comment: @ringø I think LukeG misunderstood your first comment as "is more readable _than_", which is the opposite of what you meant...right? I understood it wrong at first glance, too.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There actually is a difference, but in a very non-trivial context. Consider this code:

```
void func ( )
{
    std::cout << "Free function" << std::endl;
}

template <typename Derived>
struct test : Derived
{
    void f ( )
    {
        func(); // 1
        this->func(); // 2
    }
};

struct derived
{
    void func ( )
    {
        std::cout << "Method" << std::endl;
    }
};

test<derived> t;
```

Now, if we call `t.f()`, the first line of `test::f` will invoke the free function `func`, while the second line will call `derived::func`.

Comment: I agree with you. But in my case, there are no free functions ;)

Comment: @g.tataranni And, how should we know that, if there's no context in your question? Please provide us with [mcve], so that there's no guessing involved.

Comment: I believe this was a joke about functions being free

Comment: This reminds me: know why the leaking program gets a rather large phone bill? No `free` calls.

Comment: oh, stop it you ^^

Comment: So, this doesn't even answer the question, but gave me a silver C++ badge. Weird.

Answer (score 31):

It is impossible to tell from the snippet but possibly there are **two** *callable objects* called `func()`. The `(*this).func();` makes sure the member function is called.

A *callable object* could be (for example) a `functor` or a `lambda` expression:

**functor**

```
struct func_type
{
    void operator()() const { /* do stuff */ }
};

func_type func; // called using func();
```

**lambda**

```
auto func = [](){ /* do stuff */ }; // called using func();
```

**For example:**

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:

    // member 
    void func() { std::cout << "member function" << '\n'; }

    void other()
    {
        // lambda
        auto func = [](){ std::cout << "lambda function" << '\n'; };

        func(); // calls lambda

        (*this).func(); // calls member
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.other();
}
```

**Output:**

```
lambda function
member function
```

Comment: FTR, I had to overcome some inner resistance to upvote this answer and not downvote or edit away its misuse of the word [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor). Since _function object_ is a conventional standard meaning of the word _functor_ in the context of C++, what right have I to do that... still, just saying. I always cringe a bit when I see the word used this way.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think many C++ programmers familiar with category theory (including me) feel the same internal rant. But that's the accepted and widespread terminology, we have to accept it.

Answer (score 17):

Another case when those two lines will call different functions:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace B
{ void foo() { std::cout << "namespace\n"; } }

struct A { 
  void foo() { std::cout << "member\n"; }

  void bar()
  {
      using B::foo;
      foo();
      (*this).foo();
  }
};

int main () 
{
    A a;
    a.bar();
}
```

Comment: There is no real difference to the other examples with one member and one non-member function, is there?

Comment: @exilit different paragraphs in lookup rules. All answers shows how different rules interact with each other.

Answer (score 12):

With type dependent name, it may be different:

```
void func() { std::cout << "::func()\n"; }

struct S {
    void func() const { std::cout << "S::func()\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct C : T
{
    void foo() const {
        func();         // Call ::func
        (*this).func(); // Call S::func
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62fb126ac9fd39b7)

Comment: I've suddenly forgotten all my past CRTPs... Does this just do the same thing as `static_cast<Derived>(this)->func()`? I just assumed the latter was strictly needed, as it's used in examples so often, but now I'm wondering why if `this->func()` works just as well. I suspect there's another reason I'm not seeing.

Comment: @underscore_d: The important part is *dependent name*. `func()` doesn't depend of `T` whereas `(*this).func()`, `this->func()` or `T::func()` does depend of T.